# Best Android ORM to merging with remote REST servers

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

After search, I found ORMLite is the first Android ORM 
but I found ORMLite does not provide a solution for merging with remote REST servers.

How can I sync data between a webserver and an android app through ORMLite or other orm?

Answer (score 3):

Basically on mobile platform we have very less open source frameworks which provides both ORM and RESTful service on all the major platforms (Android, iOS, Windows).

Based on my research, please find below some of the most popular frameworks available in different areas:

**ORM**

- **Android**: [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/), [GreenDAO](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/), [Active Android](http://www.activeandroid.com/)
- **iOS**: [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)
- **Windows**: [dapper-dot-net](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), [Simple.Data](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data)

**RESTful**

- **Android**: [Restlet](https://restlet.com/), [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit)
- **iOS**: [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit)
- **Windows**: [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/)

You can also check [Siminov Framework](http://github.com/Siminov) which provides both ORM and RESTful service. It is available on all the major platforms (Android, iOS and Windows 8.1).

Comment: i think the best android sdk for RESTFull is retrofit http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Thanks @AdnenChouibi for suggesting Retrofit for Android. I have added the same in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow

It has a Direct-to-database parsing for data such as JSON so you can easily do the mapping from web service response to local database.

Check this example:

https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/blob/master/usage/ModelContainers.md